# How to pass a record parameter to a function using JPA Critera API

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

I can do this in postgresql:

```
SELECT my_func(t) FROM my_table t;
```

where `my_func` is defined as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(t my_table)
  ...
```

How can I call my_func using JPA Critera API? Doing this does not work:

```
criteriaBuilder.isTrue(
    criteriaBuilder.function("my_func", Boolean.class, myTablePath));
```

The sql it generates:

```
(my_func() = ?))
```

That is the parameter `myTablePath` is ignored.

I am using eclipselink 2.6.1 and postgresql 9.3.

Comment: so EclipseLink is incorrectly generating SQL. The "myTablePath" is defined as an ARGUMENT to the function so should put "my_func(?)". Raise a bug on your JPA provider, and perhaps try a different JPA provider

Comment: for reference, this is the submitted [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=481993).

Comment: what is myTablePath?

Comment: @Chris Path<MyTable>

Comment: You can't pass an entire entity to a function in the database and would need to pass in particular fields from the entity directly, something like "select my_func(t.id, t.name) FROM my_table t" in JPQL.  Either that, or use t.id and then modify the SQL generated directly before execution with native EclipseLink methods to generate the my_func(t) instead of the generated my_func(t.id).